# 私の作った乱数はストリーム暗号に使えますか？

Tags: アルゴリズム

x,yを任意の置換とし秘密に保ちます。aをバイナリ配列とします。
この時次の処理をします。

1. z=xyx^-1
2. y=z
3. a^=a[z]

このようにして生成された出力aは次の出力の推測が難しいでしょうか？
またこの乱数はストリーム暗号に使えますか？

https://gist.github.com/anang0g0/d6be8c3a21be68f6895f10d06ae48938

Comment: `a^=a[z]`はどのような操作なのでしょうか？

Comment: aの並び替えをした結果を、a自身にXORします。

Comment: 並び替えがどのような操作かわからない点と、固定長配列に対する暗号化であり、ストリーム暗号ではないように見えました。

Comment: ビット配列の固定点を持たない並び替えのことを置換といっているのですが、固定点を持たない任意の置換でわかりますか？このような単純な方法でもかなり性質のいい乱数ができます。問題は置換x,yを秘密にしたときに次の出力がどの程度予測可能かが知りたいです。配列の長さは固定ですが、これを再帰的に繰り返すことで長い臭気が得られるはずです。あなたは置換群を知っていますか？

Comment: アルゴリズムのサンプルコードを示すならサンプルを組んでいるプログラム言語を示した方が共通理解が進むのではないかと思いました。

Comment: もっとも、32ビットだったら2^32-1しか周期が取れないのはわかります。

Answer (score 7):

乱数や暗号は自前で考えるとたいてい穴があるものしかできないので、既成のものを使われるほうがよいです。

勉強したいのであれば、入門書としてまず「暗号技術入門(ISBN 4797382228)」を読んでみてはいかがでしょうか

---

具体的な欠陥を1つ示しておきます。

a==a[Z]になると、a^a[Z]は0となります。以後生成される数列は0となります。^a==a[Z]となっても同様です。

これは特定の初期値で起きる問題ではありません。

---

適当なパラメータで試して見ましたが、生成した値の0/1の個数に大きな偏りがありました。

あと、初期値または実行中に、x yの同じ位置に同値で周期の短い置換があると、生成される乱数の該当位置にもパターンが生じます。初期値の制約があるのであれば記載されてなければいけませんし、初期値に問題が無くとも実行中にこうならない証明が必要ですが、全く触れられていません。

乱数の数学的性質を明らかにすることと、必要な統計的性質を満たすことを示すのも、発明者の仕事です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。どのような初期値を選んだ時にそうなるかを考え、アルゴリズムの改良に努めたいと思います。